# Bootstrapping fits to a small sample

Tags: survival, bootstrap, fitting, small-sample, resampling

I have a sample of experimentally measured survival times that are quite noisy and vary stochastically. The survival probability of these events (number of events with a survival time of t or more) is expected to decay in time as a single exponential. My experimental sample size is small (10 to 15 events) and I have therefore been trying to use bootstrapping to estimate the mean decay length and its uncertainty. Basically my approach has been to sample the survival-times with replacement n times from my sample of size n. I fit each of these n samples to a single exponential and calculate its decay length. I then calculate the mean decay length and its standard deviation (SD) from the n bootstrapped samples. I however have a couple of questions on the appropriateness of my approach….

1. Am I implementing bootstrapping correctly in my application or should I by trying something different?
2. The SD in decay lengths is very large and I suspect that this is due to the small sample size and nosy data. Is there something I can do to get a more reliable estimate of the SD? For instance would it be justified for me to compute a goodness of fit statistic for each sample fitting and accept only fits above a certain threshold? In that case how can I weight my error bars to account for the probability of achieving a good fit?

Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: Why do you suspect the survival probability has an $e^{-t}$ functional form? Why not reach for the Kaplan-Meier estimator, $S(t) = \prod\limits_{t_i<t}\frac{n_i - d_i}{n_i}$ and it's variance estimator, $\text{Var}(S(t)) = S(T)^2 \sum\limits_{t_i < t} \frac{d_i}{n_i(n_i - d_i)}$. Do you have a copy of Elements of Statistical Learning on hand, pg. 243-260?

Comment: @JacobMick: Thank you for the comment. In my application, I am looking at the survival probability of single chemical bonds. Since bond dissociation is a first order reaction if decays as a single exponential.

Comment: I'm an analytical chemist, could you describe the experiment producing this data? Possibly append it to your original post.